# applying patch - 'file already exists' failure

Tags: linux, patch

I am trying to apply a patch and recieving a message of patch failure that the file already exist (kgdb patch to kernel, but the question is general for any such patch failure). What should I do in such case ?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-laptop:~/dvrrdk/DVRRDK_04.01.00.02/ti_tools/linux_lsp/kernel/linux-dvr-rdk$        
patch -p1 < /media/sf_VMshar/gdb_patch/linux-2.6.15.5-kgdb-2.4/core-lite.patch 
patching file Documentation/DocBook/Makefile
Hunk #1 FAILED at 10.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file Documentation/DocBook/Makefile.rej
The next patch would create the file Documentation/DocBook/kgdb.tmpl,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] ^C
```

Thanks,
Ran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $ patch -p1 < /media/sf_VMshar/gdb_patch/linux-2.6.15.5-kgdb-2.4/core-lite.patch 
>   patching file Documentation/DocBook/Makefile
>   Hunk #1 FAILED at 10.
>   1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file Documentation/DocBook/Makefile.rej
>   The next patch would create the file Documentation/DocBook/kgdb.tmpl,
>   which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] ^C

Error at **1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file Documentation/DocBook/Makefile.rej**

Is due to the fact that the patch is not meant for this kernel version and also 
the next patch intends to create a file **Documentation/DocBook/kgdb.tmpl** which already exists in your source code

> **Conclusion: You will have to manually apply the patch**